# Cannot remove directories via SSH when use rm and ls

Tags: linux, bash

I try to clean release directories when deploying code to the server, but I need to keep at least 5.

Now I use this command to do like I mentioned.

`rm -rf $(ls -1t /path/to/deploy/release | tail -n +6)`

Everything looks good when I ran this on the server, but It does not work when I try to run via ssh . . .

`ssh user@123.456.789.100 'rm -rf $(ls -1t /path/to/deploy/release | tail -n +6)'`

Anyone please help or suggest me. What am I do wrong?

Comment: Please define "does not work". Do you get an error? What happens?

Comment: All directories still not remove.

Comment: ssh always has an annoying habit of unquoting and unescaping things.  also, you're not getting an actual login shell, so you may have little or no PATH.  you may need to do something like **ssh user@123.456.789.100 /bin/bash -l -c 'rm -rf $(ls -1t /path/to/deploy/release | tail -n +6)'** because it may not do the expansion without invoking an actual shell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Warning: like all things that involve `rm -Rf` and "should work", the below may actually delete all files on the computer (since `ssh` is involved, that's both the local and remote computers), and possibly set your kitchen on fire. I take no responsibility for damage etc... Backups (stored somewhere other than your kitchen) are always a good thing to have, and maybe you should test with `rm -Ri` first?

You don't say what the failure is, but one thing I notice is that the `ls` command will generate a list of filenames in the `/path/to/deploy/release` directory, but `rm` will not be running in that directory, so it's going to try to delete files by those names in your home directory instead of `/path/to/deploy/release`. This is fairly easy to fix by `cd`ing into that directory first (although be sure to write the command so if the `cd` fails, it won't just randomly delete files in the wrong directory).

Another problem is that the command depends on word splitting to turn the output of `ls ... | tail ...` into a list of filenames, which will fail if any filenames contain whitespace and/or wildcards. This is trickier to solve, so I'll just ignore the problem and hope it never blows up on you.

Anyway, with the `cd` fix (and the whitespace bug unfixed), here's what I get:

```
ssh user@123.456.789.100 'cd /path/to/deploy/release && rm -Rf $(ls -1t | tail -n +6)'
```

Again, testing with `rm -Ri` (and having good backups) is recommended.